# What actually happens to a process waiting for user input?

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I want to know what actually happens to a process waiting for user input. Lets say, in my code I gave call to scanf() to read user input from console. It will internally call read() system call. But in this case there is no data to read until user gives any input. So is our process sleeping till then?

Comment: Your process will be *blocked*, which means: waiting for I/O. The kernel remembers the process's status (inside a read() system call) and will allow it to run once the I/O is available.

Comment: so does this mean TTY driver will somehow notify scheduler that data is available and scheduler will move process  to ready queue?

Comment: TTY driver is not relevant here. The program could get its input from a pipe or socket, or whatever the filedescriptor is referring to. IIRC linux uses separate lists (queues) for runnable processes and waiting processes. Once data is/isnot availabe, the proces's record will be moved between these queues. The scheduler is only concerned with the *runnable* queue.

Comment: @techiek7 Pretty much. If you know what condition variables are, that's pretty much what the kernel uses internally to notify anyone interested that something interesting happened on the tty (or whatever other file descriptor you're reading from).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's sleeping (in OS X, at least).

Try compiling and running the following C program:

```C
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int x;
    puts("Enter a number:");
    if (scanf("%d",&x)) {
        printf("You entered %d\n",x);
    }
    else {
        puts("That isn't a number");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Start the program running in the console, then open another console and enter `ps -v` at the command line. You should see something like this:

```
  PID STAT      TIME  SL  RE PAGEIN      VSZ    RSS   LIM     TSIZ  %CPU %MEM COMMAND
19544 S      0:00.01   0   0      0  2463084   1596     -        0   0.0  0.0 -bash
19574 S      0:00.01   0   0      0  2454892   1568     -        0   0.0  0.0 -bash
19582 S+     0:00.00   0   0      0  2434816    676     -        0   0.0  0.0 ./a
```

Here, `./a` is the name of the program. The entry for this process in the `STAT` column is `S+`, which means the process is sleeping (`S`) and is in the foreground (`+`).